# Update Table in the DataBase when we made changes in DataGrid contents

Tags: sql-server, wpf, database-connection, wpfdatagrid

Hi i am developing an App in WPF who will have paginated records (i am doing the pagination myself depending on the filters or in the number of records per page the user wants to be shown).

So i have never worked serious with DataGrids and what i am asking is, what is the best approach and better politic when we work with a DataGrid to update the Table in the DB?

We detect the row who have been changed, or we update the whole Table in the DB, what is the better way?

Because the user can change one row, and then other, and imagine the user changes 50 rows, the App will have to connect 50 Times with the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unit of work](http://takacsot.freeblog.hu/Files/martinfowler/unitOfWork.html) is probably the most common infrastructure solution to this problem, basically it stores the changes applied to the data and when ready executes them in a transaction to the database. There are many ORM mappers like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) that already do this for you, so id start there.

**EDIT**

See [this](http://www.codeinsanity.com/2008/09/unit-of-work-pattern.html) example implementation as it sounds like from your comments yould need to write your own version, but basically you build a list of inserts, updates, deletes that should happen and execute them all in a trasaction, first inserts, then updates, then deletes but Id recommend you look at an ORM like the ones i described above they already have this as a feature.

Comment: But i can't understand how it will be done one thing... If i have relationships between tables, when i do a query to the main Table, i am not getting the id's but the corresponding values in another column. So when i get the Row from the DataGrid, i am getting the values not the id's where the columns have a relationship with another table. So before i put my update operation in something like you suggested i probably have to get the corresponding ID's or not?

Comment: Ok perhaps you could discuss a little bit more about the data in question, are you summarizing database rows and displaying that? or is it one row in the db shows as one row on the grid?

Comment: No, i am getting the whole Table and putting as Source in the DataGrid. But that Table have foreign keys. So when i do the Query, i use Inner Joins to don't show the Id's but other Value corresponding to those ID's. So in my DataGrid i am not showing the ID's but other values. And when i want to update my DB, i am using the event OnRowEditEnding from the DataGrid, and when the event is fired i get the values from the Row who has been changed and update the DB through a SP. In this cases is in the SP where we will discover the ID's corresponding to those Values to update the Table in question?

Comment: seeing as you are not using Entity framework or other ORM mappers youd have to write a custom implementation of the unit of work pattern, so to answer your first comment, yes yould need to track the ids of the reference rows, ive edited my answer with an example implementation of unit of work, the rest is also quite interesting